# how do you get twitter timeline through oauth using javascript

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

Im currently trying to get users timeline data from twitter through the oauth process and I cant get it to work.

I tried a few things here http://bytespider.github.com/jsOAuth/ and I keep running into the same problem.

Whoa there!
There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

It cant be this hard to do this right?

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jsOAuth-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var config = {
        consumerKey: "[removed]",
        consumerSecret: "[removed]",

        requestTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
        authorizationUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
    };
    var oauth = new OAuth(config);

    oauth.fetchRequestToken(openAuthoriseWindow, failureHandler);

    function openAuthoriseWindow(url)
    {
        var wnd = window.open(url, 'authorise');
        setTimeout(waitForPin, 100);

        function waitForPin()
        {
            if (wnd.closed)
            {
                var pin = prompt("Please enter your PIN", "");
                oauth.setVerifier(pin);
                oauth.fetchAccessToken(getSomeData, failureHandler);
            }
            else
            {
                setTimeout(waitForPin, 100);
            }
        }
    }

    function getSomeData()
    {
        oauth.get("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/something/?format=jsonp", function (data) {
            console.log(data.text);
        }, failureHandler);
    }

    function failureHandler(data)
    {
        console.error(data);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also get this error in console
OPTIONS https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token 403 (Forbidden)

EDIT: Does anyone know how to do this? Cant even find a good resource on twitter. Also can you achieve this without pin and just have users enter their login details?

Thanks in advance